# Type of ANOVA test?

Tags: anova, genetics

I am trying to generate an ANOVA to test if a particular genotype (A=mutant, B= Wild-Type; control) is salt sensitive by measuring primary root length in four different medias (1=mock, 2=salt, 3=salt and hormone, 4=hormone). The mutant plant is a hormone-inducible line. Is a Two-way ANOVA appropriate for this analysis?

Comment: A pure two-way ANOVA would consider four different media, rather than if you’ve added salt to the baseline or hormone to the baseline. This takes away the model’s ability to use knowledge about the salt:hormone media to fit the salt alone or hormone alone.